# Calling procedure in DbTableAuthAdapter class in zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using the zend framework2 and make a try to login the user using the **DbTableAuthAdapter class** of zend framework2 as below

```
 $authAdapter=new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'login_user','username','password','is_active=1');
```

but instead of this i want to call a procedure like below

```
 $authAdapter=new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'CALL `sp_user_login`(?, ?)');
```

Is there anyway that i call procedure instead of binding the entity?

```
                          OR
```

Anyone tell me what is wrong in my below code

```
   use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
   $hashPassword=hash("sha256", $data["password"]);
   $subQuery="select zend_with_procedure.login_user.hash_salt from   zend_with_procedure.login_user where  zend_with_procedure.login_user.username='".$data['username']."'";

   $authAdapter=new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'login_user','username','password','concat('.$subQuery.','.$hashPassword.') AND is_active=1');

   $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['username']);
   $authAdapter->setCredential($data['password']);
   $auth=new AuthenticationService();
   $result=$auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
```

I am entering the correct username and password the it shows me invalid credentials why, Does anyone have the idea ???

Answer (score 1):

```
   use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
   $hashPassword=hash("sha256", $data["password"]);
   $subQuery="select zend_with_procedure.login_user.hash_salt from   zend_with_procedure.login_user where  zend_with_procedure.login_user.username='".$data['username']."'";
```

//Change this line  **$authAdapter=new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'login_user','username','password','concat('.$subQuery.','.$hashPassword.') AND is_active=1');
 to $authAdapter=new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'login_user','username','password',"concat(".$subQuery.",?) AND is_active=1");**

```
   $authAdapter=new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'login_user','username','password',"concat(".$subQuery.",?) AND is_active=1");

   $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['username']);
```

Change this line  **$authAdapter->setCredential($data['password']); to  $authAdapter->setCredential($hashPassword);**

```
   $authAdapter->setCredential($hashPassword);
   $auth=new AuthenticationService();
   $result=$auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
```

But not found the solution of calling a procedure!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of ZF2 you are using, but there seems to be a new CallbackCheckAdapter at least from version 2.2:

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Authentication.Adapter.DbTable.CallbackCheckAdapter.html

Maybe using that one you can call the stored procedure?

Comment: in that case it should be available - I have not yet experimented with this adapter myself, but it sounds like it offers more flexibility

Comment: I have edited my question can you suggest what should i do to achieve my goals?